# How to make horizontal UICollectionView with Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I want to display a list of product descriptions inside collection view cells and I'm using `dequee` for that.

I want to make sure that it only scrolls horizontally and not vertically at all.

The cell's width is 180px and the total number of my items is different every time.

I have tried a lot but the `scrollView` doesn't extend it's width at all.

Comment: Use my answer for easy way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973859/how-to-show-and-scroll-collectionview-two-sections-horizontal-in-swift/73705093#73705093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should  specify the layoutDirection property of your collection in viewDidLoad:

```
 if let flow =  collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
          flow.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    }
```

or you can do this in Storyboard.

Comment: Do I need to have UIScrollBar and then add collectionView as subView too?

Comment: No, you don't need it.I use a collectionViewController in my example.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 5 and easy way to do it. Use auto layout

[image]

[image]