# How to show and scroll CollectionView two sections .horizontal in swift

Tags: swift, collectionview, sections

I have given collectionview constaints like below

```
 top = leading = trailing = 0, height = 200
```

**code for collectionview:** here both sections showing in one line.. i want section 0 cells in 1st line and section 1 cells in below line and it should scroll .horizontal

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4.1
    let height = width*1.1
    
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 200)
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    
    collectionView.reloadData()
            
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0{
        return 8
    }else{
        return 10
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilesCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? FilesCollectionCell
            cell?.backgroundColor = .red
             return cell!
 
 }
        else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilesCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? FilesCollectionCell
            cell?.backgroundColor = .blue

            return cell!

        }
}
}
```

**o/p: coming like this** here red cells are in section = 0, and blue cells are section =1

present both cells coming in one line if i scroll horizontally remaining blue cells will scroll... but i need red cells(section 0) in first line and blue cells(section 1) in below line.. how do i achieve like that

[image]

**i want o/p like this: i want section 0 cells in one line and section 1 cells in another line.. like below image**

[image]

Comment: You can do this in UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

Comment: Use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, if deployment is is iOS 13+.  https://github.com/Lickability/collection-view-compositional-layout-demo

Comment: Your own custom implementation of a collection view layout is also an option if you don't want to be limited to iOS 13+. But I assume the question is really how can I achieve this _with  a UICollectionViewFlowLayout_.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is useful or not but it can be help how to put line.[image]

Click Scroll Direction

[image]

After choose which direction you want to use